# Две СУБД на одном компьютере

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Я хочу установить две СУБД на компьютер - PostgreSQL для хранения истории раздач из программы PokerTracker 4 и MySQL - буду учиться программировать :) Вопрос - не помешает ли одна СУБД другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не помешает. Каждая СУБД поднимает свой сервер и оба они крутятся на одном компьютере.

При большом желании можно даже два разных MySQL-сервера поднять на одном компьютере.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не помешает.

Вы даже можете поставить сколько угодно экземпляров одной СУБД. Например, несколько разных версий MySql. Нужно просто немного для каждой изменить настройки.